# How to display the coordinates of the points clicked on the image in Google Colab?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I need to locate the mouse click location on an image in a google colab notebook. I tried the following script but nothing happened. The following code should work in Jupyter notebooks but it doesn't work on google colab:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

f1 = 'sample.tif'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))

img = mpimg.imread(f1)

def onclick(event):
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(ix, iy)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Event handling [doesn't seem to be supported](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/86) in colab notebooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an *interactive* IPython backend, e.g. [`ipympl`](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/):

1. Installation in Colab:

```py
!pip install ipympl
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()
```

2. setup matplotlib to use it:

```py
%matplotlib ipympl
```

3. test it:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def onclick(event):
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(ix, iy)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: you are the number one genius! Well deserved the bounty. Thanks dude.

Comment: using this code, how can we wait for the user to click a data point? I ran your code but the script doesn't wait and runs next lines in the notebook. Many thanks

Comment: maybe you place an [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) after the plot command like `input("Press ENTER to proceed")`?

Comment: I tried it. That stops the data collection process.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a quick answer for this. I guess it's best to ask a new question here describing what you want to do. IIUC it's similar to this issue https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/311

Comment: Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: ipympl. Using notebook instead.
and nada

Comment: @EliaWeiss: I re-checked my answer and it works, I don't get this warning (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k--3QnRKP1TZIP4zziFDvXMOuXFiRBQS?usp=sharing)